# Protocol Buffers - Reading header (nested message) common across all messages

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am currently evaluating Protocol Buffers for use in a project (no code written as of yet). One of the things I'm unclear on is how you would read part of an encoded message, for example say I have a common header:

```
message Header {
  required uint16 msg_type = 1;
  required uint16 length = 2;
}
```

And say I deliver multiple different messages to a queue. How would the consumer work out how much data to read per message and what message type is should be constructed as?

Comment: I didn't help earlier but I learnt a lot - thx for the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no need for a `Header` message here; the most common approach is to follow the "streaming" advice [from here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming). Within that, you could either treat it as a sequence of identical [union type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union) messages, or (my preference) when writing, instead of just writing a length-prefix before each, include a varint that indicates the message type **then** the length (as a varint). The number that indicates the message type is some arbitrary map you invent, so 1 = Foo, 2 = Bar, 3 = Blap, etc). If you left-shift the message-type by 3 bits then "or" 2, then it will also be a well-formed protobuf stream *itself*, 100% identical to a `repeated YourUnionType`.

Basically, this is exactly the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242349/protobuf-streaming-lazy-serialization-api), but instead of being field 1 each time, the number varies per message-type. Most implementations have a reader/writer API that make it possible to read and write raw varints, and to length-restrict the reader API. Some implementations have helper mechanisms to support streams of heterogeneous messages directly (basically, doing all the above for you).

Comment: I've taken a look at the union stuff, looks good and what I require. To ensure I've got this correct the resultant solution would have a 'wrapper' class with a `required uint16 msg_type`, `required uint16 msg_len` and a set of `optional` message declarations. I could then define all my messages as seperate messages without concern for the length and type?

Comment: @Graeme depends exactly how you mean ;p Yes, a wrapper with `repeated` (some union type) would work fine, but that would be best done as a `repeated ContainerMessage` like in Bart's answer. I can't think of a scenario when msg_type and msg_len is useful, since that is basically handled already

Answer (score 3):

In a recent project, I used Protocol Buffers like this:

We had one 'container' message that included all the actual messages as optional members:

```
message ContainerMessage {
    optional Message1 message_1 = 1;
    optional Message2 message_2 = 2;
    //...
    optional MessageN message_N = N;
}
```

Inside an application, you could just use `ContainerMessage` as a discriminated union of the real Messages.

Between applications, we serialized/deserialized the `ContainerMessage` and sent the serialized content, prefixed with a simple header containing the length of the serialized content.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on the protocol you are using.

Note that e.g. a lot of protocols go via serial interfaces, where you might have extra lines telling when a message starts and stops.

Often, messages will have there length at a fixed offset after the message start.

In other cases, you might need to parse the message element by element to find out how much of the message is left. So a string embedded in the message may be of fixed length, or have the length at the beginning, or might have \0 as end marker.

Mostly, when you store messages in a queue for further processing, you will want to add some more information to make your life easier - like when you just have an extra signal telling you when the message stops, you might store the message internally with its length.

Comment: protobuf is a well-defined single protocol, though... is this answer specifically addressing protobuf? or is this talking about the general case?

Comment: @Zane - I think he's talking about https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/faq

Comment: @Caribou: yep sorry didn't get that. Thanks for telling me.